# Xamarin development with AsyncTask being deprecated

Tags: android, xamarin, android-asynctask, task

We are at the verge of starting an Mobile app project, and with our Microsoft stack we want to develop our app with `Xamarin`, to be more precise, `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.IOS` (so not forms).

Because our current knowledge about Xamarin in general is very limited, I am wondering what impact the deprecation of `AsyncTask` will have on Xamarin development. To my knowledge Xamarin, and .NET are heavily dependent on using `AsyncTask`?

I know deprecated does not mean it will be unavailable or unusable, but with future development in mind, would it be wise to move to Xamarin development?

**TL;DR:**
Should Xamarin Developers be worried now that `AsyncTask` is deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Xamarin can use native APIs (platform dependent) and .NET APIs (platform independent). If your app uses native APIs you can do whatever native developer can do with them, but they can work only on one platform. If they get deprecated you are in the same position as any native developer is (usually there is the workaround / new API). .NET APIs never get deprecated as it is Xamarin's job to implement them and keep them working if they use something that is deprecated, and it is impossible that .NET cannot be implemented, it is just a question of required effort. To make it clear, you are talking about the changes in native API and ask whether they influence .NET APIs. As discussed above in theory it could happen, but I don't think such problems have ever happened and this doesn't sound like something troublesome at all.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean AsyncTask from `Android.OS.AsyncTask`?

There is a big difference between `AsyncTask` and `Task` from `System.Threading.Tasks`.

AsyncTask is only available on Android, while Task is baked into .NET. `System.Threading.Task` is not going anywhere, and is a good way to write asynchronous code.

Code with `AsyncTask` would look something like:

```
public class MyTask : AsyncTask
{
    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
    }

    protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
    {
        SomeMethodRunningAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
    }
}
```

While code using `Task` would look more like:

```
public async Task DoStuffInBackground()
{
    await SomeMethodRunningAsync();
}
```

I highly doubt you are using `AsyncTask` unless you have ported some Java code or translated some code samples from Java to C#.

Comment: if cheesebaron says it about Xamarin... you can take that to the bank.  This guy is insane with his knowledge on the IDE.